# Error with SparkSession getOrCreate() function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.1 with scala 2.11 and spark-sql_2.11 in intelliJ.

When I am using `getOrCreate()` method with `SparkSession` I am getting an error. When I am commenting `getOrCreate()` code is running fine.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("SparkSQL")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/Users/temp")
    .getOrCreate()
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.checkValue(Lscala/Function1;Ljava/lang/String;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of artifcat spark-sql_2.11, it should be same as spark core...below is my POM which is working fine...

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```